# The same bytes array => Different BigInteger value in Java and C#

Tags: java, c#

I have Java and C# code as below:

```
byte[] byteArray = {
          52, 51, 102, 100, 55, 48, 48, 48, 57, 97, 57, 55, 97, 55, 100, 51, 49, 49, 99, 53, 54, 52, 52,
          48, 52, 55, 99, 99, 99, 55, 48, 48, 102, 56, 100, 48, 56, 97, 57, 100
      };
BigInteger byteArrayAsBigInt = new BigInteger(byteArray);
```

As you can see both of arrays are the same. But why BigInteger constructor in Java returns different value than in C#?

Java value for byteArrayAsBigInt:

```
435547623972009042387221878687981899647773248766318257271173050301525056529400623692496442046820
```

C# value for byteArrayAsBigInt:

```
836240090191738952707023426454050812020217962491637996803829702297801636146665723913243623568180
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I think it might have to do with how they store the data.

Comment: What makes you expect that the two would be the same? After all, they are not the same class, not the same class library, and even not the same programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that in Java Big Endian order is assumed but in C# the Little Endian is used.

From Java documentation:

> public BigInteger(byte[] val) Translates a byte array containing the
>   two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in **big-endian** byte-order:
>   the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

From C# documenation:

> BigInteger Constructor (Byte[])
>   Type: System.Byte[]
>   An array of byte values in **little-endian** order.

Comment: How can Java BigIntegers be forced to use little endian?

Comment: You can use this BigInteger pm = new BigInteger(passwordBytes, isBigEndian:true); in c# to get the java equivalent.